# MySQL error access denied

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to configure **MySQL server** on **Ubuntu 14.04**. After installing it, it worked fine, both shell mysql and MysqlWorkbench.

After I had the system rebooted everything stopped working. If I try to connect with the shell I get this:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I get this error with any user... Even with the `--skip-grant-tables` option I don't have access to anything. The connection test from the Workbench does not work either, although the server seems to be running properly.

When I was installing mysql server I was asked for a root password and I've chosen a very simple one since I'm using it for a debugging environment, so I don't think it's a misspelling issue.

I think I've tried all the tips available but still don't have access to the server.

Any help would be appreciate.
Thank you very much in advance!!

**EDIT 1:** Here's part of the my.cnf

```
 [mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
```

And the server seems to be running:

```
juan@Juancho:~$ sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                     ESCUCHAR    1158/mysqld
```

Comment: if the test connection isn't working, then your connection string is wrong (is your username and password correct for mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the official documentation, as your problem can be caused by all sorts of things. And your question doesn't describe your issue in enough detail.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/access-denied.html

I'd like to cite the Documentation for the most common "beginner errors"

> Make sure that the server has not been configured to ignore network
>   connections or (if you are attempting to connect remotely) that it has
>   not been configured to listen only locally on its network interfaces.
>   If the server was started with --skip-networking, it will not accept
>   TCP/IP connections at all. If the server was started with
>   --bind-address=127.0.0.1, it will listen for TCP/IP connections only locally on the loopback interface and will not accept remote
>   connections.

---

> If you get the following error, it means that you are using an
>   incorrect root password:
>
> > "shell> mysqladmin -u root -pxxxx ver Access denied for user
> >     'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"
>
> If the preceding error occurs even when you have not specified a
>   password, it means that you have an incorrect password listed in some
>   option file.

---

> localhost is a synonym for your local host name, and is also the
>   default host to which clients try to connect if you specify no host
>   explicitly.
>
> To avoid this problem on such systems, you can use a --host=127.0.0.1
>   option to name the server host explicitly. This will make a TCP/IP
>   connection to the local mysqld server. You can also use TCP/IP by
>   specifying a --host option that uses the actual host name of the local
>   host. In this case, the host name must be specified in a user table
>   row on the server host, even though you are running the client program
>   on the same host as the server.

Hope this might be helpful for you.

If this does not solve your problem, you probably just mistyped your password, so here's "how to get it back".

If you just set up your server, there's a good chance you got it in your bash history. To check that, type history and search for your command which in the best case contains your cleartext pass.

Most of the times the above is not an option, to work around this you have to search for your system maintenance user (on Debian located in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf) in there you'll see the username and password of your maintenance user.
Use that user to connect to your databse and change the details of your user with the grant command.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry I'm a bit newbie at this so I was not sure what kind of information would be helpful. I've edited the question and included part of the my.cnf. I get the same error using mysqladmin so, as you say, the problem seems to be a wrong password... Since I cannot change the root password because I get the same error, is there a config file where I can change it?

Comment: Here's how the magic happens, assuming you typed in your password over your shell, try the following. Type in your Commandline "history" if you're lucky you can see your password there, if that fails you can try navigating to /etc/mysql and search for a system maintenance user (on debian it's called debian.cnf). If i'm not misinformed this should be the same on Ubuntu, if you didn't set a password for your rootuser the password has to be an empty string (just leave the field blank or press enter when it prompts you for your pass).

Comment: The magic happened!! Thanks a lot!!! When I was installed mysql I was askd for a root password but no from the shell, but from a weird text editor which resembled a little bit to the old MS-DOS one, so the password wasn't stored in the commandline history. When I opened the debian.cnf file there were no 'root' entry, just "debian-sys-maint". With this user and its password (also in the file) mysql worked and I changed the mysql.user table and restore my root password. Still, I don't understand what happened after the PC rebooting... Anyway, thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: Wonderful, there are multiple possiblities what happened, it can be that you got another keyboard layout (ex. de -> en then you'll get x and y messed up) or you had caps enabled and so on. A system restart shouldn't (most definitely) alter your root passwords, that'd be a disaster