# database creation issue with eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu

```
package practice;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class DBTEst
{

  private static final String dbClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

  private static final String CONNECTION =
                          "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/emotherearth";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws
                             ClassNotFoundException,SQLException
  {
    System.out.println(dbClassName);
    Class.forName(dbClassName);

      Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("user","paulr");
    p.put("password","welcome");

    Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION,p);

    System.out.println("It works !");
    c.close();
    }
}
```

i am new to database and so to sql.. i just configured the mysql with eclipse in ubuntu OS. but when i am trying to run the program i am getting the error like below.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'paulr'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1086)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:928)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1750)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1290)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2493)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2311)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:347)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at practice.DBTEst.main(DBTEst.java:32)
```

i have found the same question in the forum but didn't solved my issue ...may it's due to OS change if not that pls forgive my ignorance and please guide through this..thanks for your help...root password i've set while installing mySQL is "welcome"..

Comment: The exception is clear: that username and password does not have access to the database.  Speak to the DBA.  You have to GRANT access to that username and password connecting to the database from that host.

Comment: how to speak to DBA...what is  DBA ...pardon don't know anything abt database...trying to learn..:)

Comment: Database administrator - the person who owns the database. If that's you, you need to learn about how to do it. You usually create the database and tables outside of Java. You interact with a schematic that exists.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html.  You might just need to GRANT permission to username "paulr" and password "welcome" to connect from localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you did not set up the user `paulr` correctly in MySQL when you set it up, or you might have made the common mistake of overlooking that fact that MySQL does account access based on the client's IP address or hostname. Many people forget to include `localhost` and/or `127.0.0.1` in the user setup.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26234768/639520